# Add SKShapeNode to UIViewController (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

Right now I have created a SKScene containing a SKShapeNode, and I am adding this SKScene to an UIViewController. Is it possible to add directly a SKShapeNode to an UIViewController?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No it is not.  An `SKShapeNode` (or any other type of `SKWhatever`) cannot be added to the `UIViewController`.  It is part of Sprite Kit, which is the only thing that can handle SK objects.

To give an analogy, it is like putting a compact car's engine (`SKShapeNode`) into a semi-truck (`UIViewController`).  They are both automobiles (things that display), but are for completely different purposes.